# Creating sub-site of sub-site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: site, sub-site

I am using SharePoint 2010.

How can I create a sub-site of a sub-site?

Like this: `http://ParentSite/ChildSite/BabySite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase you need to know **"from where"** do you create a subsite, The flow is fairly straightforward.

1. Go to site settings of your Parent Site
2. Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Administration section > Sites and Workspaces > Create

Else the shortcut is `http://parentsite/_layouts/mngsubwebs.aspx`

After you create your child site, repeat the same steps as outlined in 1.

Else the shortcut is `http://parentsite/child/_layouts/mngsubwebs.aspx`

From here on you can create the baby site. Incase you want a inner baby , just follow the same steps over again . SharePoint supports subsite under subsite to a large number, so you should plan it carefully and make them contextually relevant.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a site in SharePoint it is created in the site you are in at the time.  So to answer the question:

1. Create Child site
2. Navigate to Child site
3. Create Baby site

Baby site will be a sub-site of Child site.